# CSS Class by element ID?

Tags: css

I have a following css

```
#container
{
        border:1px solid black;
}
#container #header
{
    color:blue;
}

#container #footer
{
    color:red;
}
```

Can i write it as

```
#container
{
        border:1px solid black;
        #header
        {
            color:blue;
        }

        #footer
        {
            color:red;
        }
}
```

So the #header and #footer are still select as #container's childs element.
Or i need to use some css framework like .LESS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, CSS doesn't support that. I agree, it would be useful. However, you're right, it looks like LESS supports it.

Comment: thanks you very much~ I have a look on CSS3, it still not support. :(

Answer (score 1):

***Yes*** only if you *[use SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)*, not possible in vanilla CSS.

Answer (score 0):

CSS doesn't support that syntax out of the box, so yes you would have to use .LESS